# How to calculate multiple user input (IF statements ) to return a total

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

Good Morning/Afternoon,

I'm having an issue where the code works fine, aside from exception handling the course has not reached that staged so please omit these functions. I setup a variable to be used to calculate the total bill, however when compiling it keeps saying "floodSort" and "pipeSort" are not initialized.

I tried using separate IF statements to assign the value of the variable, perhaps this is not the correct way. I also attempted a full set of If statements written in comment under the program. This would not return the desired results. The same scenario the variables are not initialized.

**Question: What would be the best way to return the customers total bill?**

I was extremely excited and grateful for the assistance on my previous post, any assistance or suggestions are greatly appreciated. I'm taking online classes because none are offered in person so this is the best I can get!

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

/*Author: 
  Date: 
  Program: Write a class "Plumbers" that handles emergency plumbing calls. The company handles natural floods and burst pipes. If the customer selects a flood, the program must prompt the user to determine the amount of damage for pricing. Flood charging is based on the numbers of damaged rooms. 1 room costs $300.00, 2 rooms cost $500.00, and 3 or more rooms cost $750.00. Pipe bursting is based on the number of pipes: 1 pipe costs $50.00, 2 pipes cost $70.00, and 3 or more pipes cost $100.00
  */

public class Plumbers


{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   { 
   //Declarations 

      double floodSort;
      double pipeSort;
      double totalCost;
      int answer;
      int floAnswer;
      int pipeAnswer;
      // Declare flood room damage cost: 1 room costs $300.00, 2 rooms cost $500.00, and 3 or more rooms cost $750.00
      double floRoom1 = 300.00;
      double floRoom2 = 500.00;
      double floRoom3 = 750.00; // 3 or more rooms

      // Delcare pipe burst damage by number of pipes: 1 pipe costs $50.00, 2 pipes cost $70.00, and 3 or more pipes cost $100.00
      double pipeDam1 = 50.00;
      double pipeDam2 = 70.00;
      double pipeDam3 = 100.00; // 3 or more pipes

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Press 1 if a flood or burst pipes occured or Press 2 for other options: ");
      answer = scan.nextInt();


      switch (answer)
      {

         case 1: 


            System.out.print("How many rooms were affected by flood damage 1, 2, 3 or more?: ");
            floAnswer = scan.nextInt(); 


            System.out.print("How many pipes are damaged? 1, 2, 3 or more?: ");
            pipeAnswer = scan.nextInt();


            // 1 room was damaged
            if (floAnswer == 1)
            {
               floodSort = 300.00;
               System.out.println("The cost of flood damage will be " + floRoom1 );
            }
            // 2 rooms were damaged
            if (floAnswer == 2)
            {
               floodSort = 500.00;
               System.out.println("The cost of flood damage will be " + floRoom2 );
            }

            // 3 or more rooms damaged
            if (floAnswer >= 3)
            {
               floodSort = 750.00;
               System.out.println("The cost of flood damage will be " + floRoom3 );
            }



            // one pipe was damaged
            if (pipeAnswer == 1)
            {
               pipeSort = 50.00;
               System.out.println("The cost of pipe damage will be " + pipeDam1 );
            }
            // 2 pipes were damaged
            if (pipeAnswer == 2)
            {
               pipeSort = 70.00;
               System.out.println("The cost of pipe damage will be " + pipeDam2 );
            }

            // 3 or more pipes were damaged
            if (pipeAnswer >= 3)
            {
               pipeSort = 100.00;
               System.out.println("The cost of pipe damage will be " + pipeDam3 );
            }
           // determine total cost of visist.
            totalCost = floodSort + pipeSort;
            System.out.println("Total cost of visit: $" +totalCost);



            break;

         case 2:
            System.out.println("Please contact your local office as this number only handles emergency calls, Thank you.");//exit from program;
            break;

         default :
            System.out.println("invalid choice")   ;
            break;
      }



   }

}// end of class

/*


            //  IF statement to sort FLOOD pricing total

               if (floAnswer == 1)
               {
               floodSort = 300.00;
               }   

               if (floAnswer == 2)
               {
               floodSort = 500.00;
               }

               if (floAnswer >= 3)
               {
               floodSort = 750.00;
               }


               //  IF statement to sort PIPE burst pricing total

               if (pipeAnswer == 1)
               {
               pipeSort = 50.00;
               }

               if (pipeAnswer == 2)
               {
               pipeSort = 70.00;
               }

               if (pipeAnswer >= 3)
               {
               pipeSort = 100.00;
               }


               totalCost = (floodSort + pipeSort);
               System.out.println("Total bill comes too: $" + totalCost);
               */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that any of those IF statements will get hit. Since you don't assign initial values to floodSort and pipeSort they may never be initialized. If you want to be sure they are initialized you can set them to 0 at the start

```
 double floodSort = 0;
 double pipeSort = 0;
```

If I was to rewrite this code I would use arrays instead of separate variables like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/*Author:
  Date:
  Program: Write a class "Plumbers" that handles emergency plumbing calls. The company handles natural floods and burst pipes. If the customer selects a flood, the program must prompt the user to determine the amount of damage for pricing. Flood charging is based on the numbers of damaged rooms. 1 room costs $300.00, 2 rooms cost $500.00, and 3 or more rooms cost $750.00. Pipe bursting is based on the number of pipes: 1 pipe costs $50.00, 2 pipes cost $70.00, and 3 or more pipes cost $100.00
  */

public class Plumbers


{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Declarations

        //double totalCost;
        int answer;
        int floAnswer;
        int pipeAnswer;
        // Declare flood room damage cost: 1 room costs $300.00, 2 rooms cost $500.00, and 3 or more rooms cost $750.00
        double[] floRoom = {300.00,500.00,750}; 

        // Delcare pipe burst damage by number of pipes: 1 pipe costs $50.00, 2 pipes cost $70.00, and 3 or more pipes cost $100.00
        double[] pipeDam = {50.00,70.00,100.00};

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Press 1 if a flood or burst pipes occured or Press 2 for other options: ");
        answer = scan.nextInt();

        switch (answer)
        {
            case 1:

                System.out.print("How many rooms were affected by flood damage 1, 2, 3 or more?: ");
                floAnswer = scan.nextInt();
                if (floAnswer > 3) floAnswer = 3;

                System.out.print("How many pipes are damaged? 1, 2, 3 or more?: ");
                pipeAnswer = scan.nextInt();
                if (pipeAnswer > 3) pipeAnswer = 3;

                double totalCost = floRoom[floAnswer] + pipeDam[pipeAnswer];
                System.out.println("Total cost of visit: $" +totalCost);

                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Please contact your local office as this number only handles emergency calls, Thank you.");//exit from program;
                break;

            default :
                System.out.println("invalid choice")   ;
                break;
        }



    }

}// end of class
```

Comment: Geez, I think we are going into arrays next chapter or so. That looks very clean and easy to follow. I guess us students need to know the long way before knowing how to make a shorter version. Extremely helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put double floodSort = 0; and double pipeSort = 0; in the initialization for example...Just need to give it an initialization value

Comment: *Facepalm!
thank you so very much... I missed that detail.
works completely fine, the comment if statements will not be needed.